# $e^{X_t - \frac{t^3}{6}}$ is a martingale - show it

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am trying to use Ito's integral properties to prove it is a martingale, but am getting stuck in the preliminaries.

More so, I wanted to confirm, do I use this formula?[image]

Comment: Sure if you understand your second process $Y_t$ is deterministic.  However, it might be easier to understand using Ito's lemma with a function that has time dependence $df(t, X_t)$.  That is what the above reduces to when $Y_t$ is deterministic.

Comment: Using your suggestion, will the partial derivatives attached to $(dY)^2$ and $(dX)(dY)$ disappear?

Comment: The partial derivatives won't, but those terms will. $(dY)^2 = (dX)(dY) = 0$.

Comment: what is the SDE for $X_t$?

Comment: yep, that is what I meant.

the only thing that is bothering me is, I end up with:

$$e^{X_t - \frac{t^3}{6}}dX_t - \frac{t^2}{2}e^{X_t-\frac{t^3}{6}}dt + 0.5 e^{X_t-\frac{t^3}{6}}dt$$ Which doesn't simplify any further

Have i made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: What is $X$? $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $Y_t = f(X_t, t) = \exp(X_t - t^3/6)$. Assume $dX_t = m(t) dt + s(t) dW_t$ so $(dX_t)^2 = s(t)^2 dt$. Now apply Ito's lemma to $Y_t$:
$$
\begin{split}
dY_t &= \exp(X_t - t^3/6) \frac{-t^2dt}{2} + \exp(X_t - t^3/6) (dX_t)
                                           + \exp(X_t - t^3/6) (dX_t)^2/2 \\
     &= Y_t
        \left[ \frac{-t^2dt}{2} + m(t) dt + s(t) dW_t + \frac{s(t)^2dt}{2} \right]
\end{split}
$$
which is a martingale when
$$
s(t)^2/2 + m(t) - t^2/2 = 0.
$$
The simplest example would be $m(t) = 0$ and $s(t) = t$, so the process $(X_t)$ such that $dX_t = t dW_t$ would make $Y_t = f(X_t,t)$ into a martingale.